# How to migrate a java command pattern using runnable to PHP 7.4?

Tags: java, php, runnable, porting, command-pattern

For studying purpose, I am trying to migrate this Java Command Pattern example to PHP:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52110/command-pattern-implementation

[image: UML diagram]

[As @simon commented](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/52115), using method reference operator, would modernize quite a bit the code:

```
class MyCommand implements Order {
    private final Runnable action;

    public MyCommand(Runnable action) {
         this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
         action.run();
    }
}
```

And then you could create commands like this:

```
MyCommand bsc = new MyCommand(stock::buy);
MyCommand ssc = new MyCommand(stock::sell);
```

My current PHP implementation is here: https://3v4l.org/iIHn9

So what is the best approach to implement the **MyCommand Class in PHP**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Evgeniy already mentioned you can use [call_user_func()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).

Since there is many ways how to solve this I've added my solutions to your question. You can also make an object `callable` by adding the [__invoke](https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) method inside a class. It's also possible to return a `callable` function. I've added in total 3 examples for it.

This is my version of your `MyCommand` class in java which is used for all 3 examples.

```
class MyCommand implements Order
{
    private $action;

    public function __construct(callable $action)
    {
        $this->action = $action;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // Option 1) use call_user_function
        call_user_func($this->action);

        // Option 2) define it as a variable and call it by adding `()`
        //$action = $this->action;
        //$action();
    }
}
```

**Example 1) A callable function** (https://3v4l.org/FVTEK)

```
class Stock
{
    public function buy(): callable
    {
        return function () {
            echo "You want to buy stocks via callable function" . PHP_EOL;
        };
    }

    public function sell(): callable
    {
        return function () {
            echo "You want to sell stocks via callable function" . PHP_EOL;
        };
    }
}

$stock = new Stock();
$bsc = new MyCommand($stock->buy());
$ssc = new MyCommand($stock->sell());

$bsc->execute();
$ssc->execute();
```

**Example 2) A callable class** (https://3v4l.org/BrKjv)

```
class StockBuy
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        echo "You want to buy stocks via __invoke()" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class StockSell
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        echo "You want to sell stocks __invoke()" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$bsc = new MyCommand(new StockBuy());
$ssc = new MyCommand(new StockSell());

$bsc->execute();
$ssc->execute();
```

**Example 3) Static member functions which return callable. Just an example to be more close to java** (https://3v4l.org/PKk4B)

```
class Stock
{
    static public function buy(): callable
    {
        return function () {
            echo "You want to buy stocks via callable function" . PHP_EOL;
        };

        // or as callable object
        // return new StockBuy();
    }

    static public function sell(): callable
    {
        return function () {
            echo "You want to sell stocks via callable function" . PHP_EOL;
        };

        // or as callable object
        // return new StockSell();
    }
}

$bsc = new MyCommand(Stock::buy());
$ssc = new MyCommand(Stock::sell());
$bsc->execute();
$ssc->execute();
```

Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP you can achieve the same using [`call_user_func`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) that is similar to method reference in Java.

```
<?php

namespace StockCommandNS;

//Command interface
interface Order {
    public function execute();
}

//Receiver class
class StockTrade {

    public function buy() {
        print("You want to buy stocks\n");
    }

    public function sell() {
        print("You want to sell stocks\n");
    }
}

//Invoker class
class Agent {

    public function placeOrder(Order $order) {
        $order->execute($order);
    }
}

//ConcreteCommand Class
class GenericOrder implements Order {

    private $action;

    public function __construct($action) {
        $this->action = $action;
    }

    public function execute() {
        call_user_func($this->action);
    }
}

$stock = new StockTrade();
$bsc = new GenericOrder([$stock, 'buy']);
$ssc = new GenericOrder([$stock, 'sell']);
$agent = new Agent();
$agent->placeOrder($bsc); // Buy Shares
$agent->placeOrder($ssc); // Sell Shares
```

Output for 7.2.0 - 7.4.3

```
You want to buy stocks
You want to sell stocks
```

Run PHP code: https://3v4l.org/fWo20

Another less clean option is to use variable function.

```
class GenericOrder implements Order {

    private $stock;
    private $action;

    public function __construct($stock, $action) {
        $this->stock = $stock;
        $this->action = $action;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $method = $this->action;
        $this->stock->$method();
    }
}

$bsc = new GenericOrder($stock, 'buy');
$ssc = new GenericOrder($stock, 'sell');
```

I'm not sure that the approach with method references is better in all cases. 
As a rule of thumb, you should always consider on per-use-case basis when to use method references or anonymous function is the Command pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some references regarding PHP's design patterns:

https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README.html
https://phptherightway.com/#design_patterns